# SimpleTurtle Class

Tags: java, turtle-graphics

I wrote a class expending the `SimpleTurtle` class, and I have a little problem.

When using the `turnRight`/`turnLeft` method, if I use a variable for the angle, the turtle doesn't turn at all:

- When I write `turnLeft(90);` it works as it should.
- When I write `turnLeft(deg);` it does nothing.

Do you have any idea why it's happening?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SmartTurtle drawer=new SmartTurtle();
    drawer.draw(6,100);
}   
public void draw(int sides, double size)
{
    int deg;
    deg=((sides-2)/(sides*180));
/*  if(sides==3)
        deg=120;
    if(sides==4)
        deg=90;
    if(sides==5)
        deg=72;
    if(sides==6)
        deg=60;
    hide();
*/
    tailDown();
    for(int i=0;i<sides;i++)
    {
        turnLeft(deg);
        moveForward(size);
    }
    tailUp();
}
```

Comment: Not without some code, please edit and add relevant part of your class

Comment: What is the value of `deg`? A value of `0` would have that effect.

Comment: My guess `int deg = (int) rand()*360;` which should be `int deg = (int) (rand()*360);` or so.

Comment: don't post in comments, edit your question

Comment: @user3460551 Edit your question (Please don't post your code as a comment). Also, what is the value of sides?

Comment: the variable "deg" is int, and I need to draw a polygon, so I want deg to be:
`deg=((sides-2)/(sides*180));`

Comment: I just figured it out, it was about making sides double and than cast it to int

Answer (score 0):

Ideas:

- deg **has no value** (it´s value is 0)
- turnLeft(deg) in launching a **error** that you can´t wath.

You should read a bit about **java debugging** with developement tools as **eclipse** (https://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=503) once you take the shot on debugging this kind of tasks will be easy to solve for you.